# Distributing a separate dependency on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have some custom Tensorflow code I have in the `contrib/` subdirectory of the project (all other parts of the code are standard Tensorflow from the official distribution).

I would like to be able to distribute this code as an external dependency on Tensorflow, such that I can distribute the library via `pip` and depend on the binary packages available for Tensorflow in `pip` as well.

My main goal is that I don't want to have users of my code have to compile the full Tensorflow tree (with my custom code only in `contrib/`) just to get my custom code / module.

Is this possible to do, and if so how?

Comment: Can you use user ops? I've been distributing my ops as ".so" files like [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_probe_ops) . If you want users to be able to build your code from source, the ideal solution would have your project depend on TensorFlow as a git submodule. However, my co-worker ran into some snags using this approach (Bazel's select was insensitive to workspace which broke some BUILD macros), and he ended up just writing scripts that copy his code into TensorFlow official tree, and then package up result out of bazel-bin/.runfiles directories

Comment: Ah yes, I should be able to use this method. Good to know that building outside of the Tensorflow tree is difficult; building in `user_ops` shouldn't be a problem for me.